# Extends report is displayed in the sent folder however, never received by the recipient

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, extends

When I send extent report automatically after completion of suite execution then report is appearing in sent item but this email is not appearing in the recipient's inbox.
Moreover in extent report attachment virus detected and that is the reason the report is not sent to recipient's inbox.
Can anyone help me out?

[how the report is being generating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWDqw.png) [Virus is being displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXROP.png)

It should be received